# Java 11 is not installed but still getting the error as "class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0"

Tags: java, extentreports

I am trying to implement extent report v5.1.1 into my java project which uses java 8 as the Version,but when I try to execute the script via the ant command,I am getting the error as **class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0**
Even though I cross-checked the compilation version in Eclipse, it still shows the same error if we try to execute via testNG too.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to [Issue With Version 5.1.0](https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-java/issues/394) ExtendReports Version 5.1.0 and later require Java 11.

If you cannot upgrade your project to Java 11 you must use an earlier version of ExtendReports. Currently the latest version before 5.1.0 is version 5.0.9 (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports)